# Is there a suitable design pattern to refactor this C# code

Tags: c#, .net, generics, design-patterns, refactoring

I have 2 different 3rd party assemblies that provide  the same API for a business service and  using the same class names (~40 classes/types/extensions) but located in different assemblies:

```
    Company.Assemply.V1
    Company.Assemply.V2
```

I reference both assemblies in the project.

There is no common interface for these assemblies, and no way for the 3rd party to provide a common interface

So, the c# compiler treat every type in the two assemblies as a different type.

I want to implement a class `Myservice`  for every assembly to support both versions V1/V2.

I use the following code to implement `Myservice.V1.Myclass`

```
    //#define V1

    #if V1
       using  Company.Assemply.V1;
    #else
       using  Company.Assemply.V2;
    #endif

    #if V1
      namespace Myservice.V1
    #else
      namespace Myservice.V2
    #endif
    {
       //my implementation that use all classes /types in any v1/v2 assembly
        class MyClass {.... }
     }
```

Then i copy and paste the same code in other c# file  `MyClassV2.cs`  (about 400 lines) to get  `Myservice.V2.Myclass` and uncomment the compiler flag `#define V1`

I can't use Generics

```
        MyClass  <T> where T:??
```

because there is no common interface for T

The two class are working fine.

The problem is when maintaining v1, I have to copy/paste the code in the other file `MyClassV2.cs` and uncomment the compiler flag `#define V1` to  support V2.

Is there a better way / suitable design pattern/refactoring technique  that can solve such a problem. 
I  want  to use/maintain  one code base and avoid copy/paste for the other class version.

Give me an example of refactoring the above code.

Comment: how to pass the corresponding assembly that resolve the dynamics at runtime?

Comment: Wrap them in your own Classes. Then you can decide how the Inheritance looks freely. When you use the MVVM pattern, you have to do a lot of wrapping like that.

Comment: @Christopher, can you give me an example for the both assemblies.

Comment: When you use the MVVM pattern, you need ChangeNotification on all the Properties of every ViewModel class. 95% of all Model classes do not have change notificaiton. Or even properties that you can override (mostly they have fields). Solution: You write your own classes. Their sole purpose is to hold a Model class in a private variable. All their Properties do nothing but wrap around the calls to the fields. All their functions jsut wrap around the model functions. End result: The Model classes can stay oblivious of realiy. You get the exact proeprties and classes you want.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use the [adapter pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter), which is a common way to add abstractions to BCL and 3rd party code that doesn't utilize them. For example, you have a type in the 3rd party assembly named `MyClass` and both `V1` and `V2` share the same members:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    // All members of MyClass 
    // (except we have a special case for DoSomething() because it
    // has a return type SomeType we also need to adapt to ISomeType).

    ISomeType DoSomething();
}

public class MyClassV1 : V1.MyClass, IMyClass
{
    // No need to re-implement members (base class satisfies interface)
    // However, if there are return parameters, you will need to 
    // also use a decorator pattern to wrap them in another adapter.

    public override ISomeType DoSomething()
    {
        return new SomeTypeV1(base.DoSomething());
    }

}

public class MyClassV2 : V2.MyClass, IMyClass
{
}

public interface ISomeType
{
     // All members of SomeType
}

public class SomeTypeV1 : ISomeType
{
    private readonly SomeType someType;

    public SomeType(SomeType someType)
    {
        this.someType = someType;
    }

    // re-implement all members and cascade the call to someType
}
```

And then you can just use `IMyClass` in your application, using DI to inject whichever one you need.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyClass myClass;

    public HomeController(IMyClass myClass)
    {
        this.myClass = myClass
    }
}
```

If you need to switch between implementations at runtime, consider the [strategy pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32415954/181087).

Comment: Some methods in the classes return/have parameters of  DataType located in the assembly. Do I have to build  a separate adapter for these types?

Comment: In that case you will need a decorator pattern to wrap the returned instance from the API. See my updated answer. There may be other special cases as well that need wrapping in a decorator depending on how many other types from the library the API exposes.