# Get different interface in two controllers with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I want to use different interface in different controller.

```
public interface IMessenger {
    Id {get; set;}
    void Send();
}
```

I have two class implement two same interface.

```
public class SmsSender : IMessenger {
    public Id {get; set;}
    public void Send() {
         //logic here
    }    
}

public class MailSender : IMessenger {
    public Id {get; set;}
    public void Send() {
         //logic here
    }    
}
```

Two Controllers:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {

    private readonly IMessenger _messenger;

    public HomeController(IMessenger messenger) {
        _messenger = messenger;
    }
}


public class Home2Controller : Controller {

    private readonly IMessenger _messenger;

    public HomeController(IMessenger messenger) {
        _messenger = messenger;
    }
}
```

Autofaq setup:

```
builder.RegisterType<MailSender>().As<IMessenger>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<SmsSender>().As<IMessenger>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

How can I get **SmsSender** in HomeController and **MailSender** in Home2Controller?

Comment: Are you open in using other IOC containers? I believe Ninject has this feature

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dependency injection type-selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34329203/dependency-injection-type-selection)

Comment: [There's an entire FAQ on this topic.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you register your component you can tell *Autofac* which dependency to choose using the `WithParameter` method.

```
builder.RegisterType<Service>()
       .As<IService>()
       .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDependency),
                      (pi, c) => new XDependency());
```

In order to avoid the `new XDependency` code and let *Autofac* create the dependency, you can resolve a named registration.

```
builder.RegisterType<XDependency>().Named<IDependency>("X");
builder.RegisterType<YDependency>().Named<IDependency>("Y");
```

and resolve it using `c.ResolveNamed<IDependency>("X")`

Another solution would be to let the component choose which dependency it wants using `IIndex<TKey, TService>`. To use this, you have to register your `IDependency` as named registrations and inject `IIndex<String, IDependency>`.

```
public class Service 
{
    public Service(IIndex<String, IDependency> dependencies)
    {
        this._dependency = dependencies["X"]; 
    }

    private readonly IDependency _dependency;
}
```

For more information you can have a look at the FAQ on the *autofac* documentation : [How do I pick a service implementation by context](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. Autofac won't be able to figure out the differences. Better to separate them into two different interfaces, inject the one you need into controllers. From the design point of view the dependency is clearer as well. If there is a need, both interfaces can implement IMessenger.