# How to implement Unity DI for my scenario to load class dynamically

Tags: c#, unity-container

I want to load my class dynamically by using the Unity DI container based on country code saved in variable.

Our win apps has a shipping functionality for which we use web service developed by 3rd party company like UPS, FedEx and Purolator.

Now how should I design my code with unity, so that I could load my shipping class based on country code stored in variable?

Suppose this is my sample or proposed class design:

```
   public interface IShip
    {
        string Ship();
    }

    public class UPS : IShip
    {
        public string Ship()
        {
        }
    }

    public class FedEX : IShip
    {
        public string Ship()
        {
        }

    }

    public class Purolator : IShip
    {
        public string Ship()
        {
        }

    }
```

How can I use unity to load class based on variable value.

What if `GB` is stored in variable and I want to load UPS class and invoke ship function ?

Suppose `FR` is stored in a variable and I want to load UPS class and invoke ship function ?

Suppose if `US` is stored in variable and I want to load FedEx class and invoke ship function ?

Suppose `CA` is stored in variable and I want to load Purolator class and invoke ship function ?

Comment: Can you show the consuming code of IShip?

Comment: the class design from my thought. code not started. i like to know how to use unity DI which load class dynamically based on country code supplied at run time.

Comment: Use Named registration of multiple implementation with interface. Similar [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23669951/881798).

Answer (score 2):

You can register your classes by name, and resolve them depending on your condition:

```
container.RegisterType<IShip, UPS>("UPS");
container.RegisterType<IShip, FedEX>("FedEX");
container.RegisterType<IShip, Purolator>("Purolator");

public IShip GetShippment(string c)
{

    if (c == "GB" || c == "FR")
        return container.Resolve<IShip>("UPS");

    if (c == "US")
        return container.Resolve<IShip>("FedEX");

    if (c == "CA")
        return container.Resolve<IShip>("Purolator");

    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
...
var shippment = GetShippment("CA");
shippment.Ship();
```

Comment: thanks for your code but u did not show how to call right ship function........would u plzz add bit more code to show how to call ship function ? thanks

Comment: @Thomas just call method `Ship`

Comment: i will test your code and let u know. thanks a lot :)