# Injecting runtime dependency in unity

Tags: unity-container

My application is based on ASP.NET WebAPI and I am using Unity for DI. 
My ResourceProvider class has a dependency of type string culturename.
As culturename would be different in every web request.

How should I register ResourceProvider in UnityConfig to be able to pick new culturename for each webrequest.

```
public ResourceProvider(string cultureName)
    {
        this.cultureName = cultureName;
    }
```

While registering ResourceProvider

```
container.RegisterType<IResourceProvider, ResourceProvider>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: Where do you store the logic to provide a new cultername for each request?

Comment: Currently a MessageHandler reads it from the HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages and sets it to Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture. However it is not just about culturename, I need to inject some other similar properties like the correlationId etc. So I am looking for an exiting pattern to do the same.

Comment: You can use **InjectionFactory**, **InjectionConstructor** (or others **InjectionMember**) during register type, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16185690/5359302.
Also, you can use resolve type with parameters that will be passed into constructor https://stackoverflow.com/a/1457486/5359302